# Error while creating an External Table in hive and transfer twitter data in avro format to this table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, flume-twitter, bigdata

I used Flume to fetch Twitter data. This data is stored as avsc file in hdfs. I created avro schema file "tweeter.avsc" and saved it in hdfs.
But when I am trying to Create External Table using command below I get error.

Command:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweeter    
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'    
STORED as   
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'    
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'    
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/tweets2'
TBLPROPERTIES 
('avro.schema.url'='http://localhost:50070/explorer.html#/user/cloudera/tweets.avsc');
```

But I get an Error:

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException
>   Encountered exception determining schema. Returning signal schema to
>   indicate problem: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected
>   character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String,
>   array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')  at [Source:
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@7851cf69;
>   line: 1, column: 2])

Please help.